# Manage Wordpress links for a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hyperlink

I have to do a plugin in `Wordpress` and I have a question.
I need to have a structure like `domain.it/job/place/somethingelse` where each job has multiple places and each place has multiple something else.
Every page has the same layout; example:

```
TITLE: [job] in [place].
SOME TEXT
[somethingelse]
```

So, I should do an unique page where I can extract information from the link and echo my page.
Can anyone help me to manage this problem in `wordpress`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, a good solution would be to create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/custom_post_type) "job". Then you can add the fields for job title etc to it.
To save the place, you can easily create something similar to post tags. Instead of naming them "tag" you call them "location" for your post type and select the right one for each job.
Using custom post types, you can/must create separate templates for them. It's like page template, but you display the values of your job instead of a page. In this template, you can add the default text easily. (It's also possible to create templates for the jobs based on other factors, like one template for each job category.